# how to upload multiple images from multiple fields from HTML form to node js into two folders then to MongoDB?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

I have done the first part correctly (upload the images to their folders), but I can't
upload the images to the DB

form.html
the form to upload the images while the user sign up for a new account

```
<div>
<label for="image">Upload Image</label>
<input type="file" id="image1" name="image1" value="" >
</div><div>
<label for="image">Upload Image</label>
<input type="file" id="image2" name="image2" value="" >
</div>
```

multer.js
to save the images in the folders

```
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.fieldname === 'image1') {
        cb(null, './logic/uploads');
    }
    else if (file.fieldname === 'image2') {
        cb(null, './logic/uploadp');
    }
},
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    console.log('New image saved!')
}
});

module.exports = multer({ storage: storage });
```

route

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('../logic/multer')

const { userSignup, userLogin } = require('../logic/Membership_Application');
router.post('/Register', 

   multer.fields([
   { name: 'image1', maxCount: 1 },
   { name: 'image2', maxCount: 1 },
   ]),
   userSignup
);

router.post('/login', userLogin);
module.exports = router;
```

logic (data insertion)

```
const UsersSchema = await new jcs({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        phone: req.body.phone,
        password: hashedPassword,
        nationality: req.body.nationality,
       //here is the error(it was working with multer.singel but not with multer,fields)
        img: {
            data: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/uploads/' + req.file.filename)),
            contentType: 'image/png'
        },
        img2: {
            data: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/uploadp/' + req.file.filename)),
            contentType: 'image/png'
        }
    }).save();
```

model(Database schema)

```
const db = require('mongoose');
//Database Creation
const UsersSchema = new db.Schema
    ({
            name: { type: String },
            email: { type: String },
            phone: { type: String },
            password: { type: String },
            nationality: { type: String },
            
            img:
            {
                    data: Buffer,
                    contentType: String,
            },
            img2:
            {
                    data: Buffer,
                    contentType: String,
            },

    })


var Users = db.model("Users", UsersSchema);
module.exports = Users;
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
require('dotenv/config');

const MembershipApplicationRouter = require('./route/Membership_Application');
const AdminRouter = require('./route/admin')

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const db = require('mongoose');
db.connect('mongodb-link',
{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
const connection = db.connection;
connection.on('connected', () => { console.log("conected with cloud") });
connection.on('error', () => { console.log("error with database") });
app.use('/admin', AdminRouter);
app.use([
bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }), 
express.json(), 
express.urlencoded({ extended: true })]);
app.use(cors());


app.use('/membershipApplication', MembershipApplicationRouter);



var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
console.log("Server Up and running");
})
module.exports = app;
```

I have this error msg

```
New image saved!
New image saved!
C:\Users\abs2\Desktop\m_a_test\logic\Membership_Application.js:79
            data: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/uploads/' + req.file.filename)),
                                                                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename')
at userSignup (C:\Users\abs2\Desktop\m_a_test\logic\Membership_Application.js:79:84)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to store the file’s location in your server to mongoDB.

So that whenever you to access the file you fetch it’s location then return it back!!

Comment: How can I do that (syntax)